# Is there a python-syntax similar to matlab for selecting rows and columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matlab, syntax

If I have a list of several lists (of floats) like

```
list = [
       [111, 111, 4523.123, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4526.15354, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4580.112, 111, 111],
       ]
```

How can I get the third column without using loops? If it were a matrix in matlab I would do  `list(:,3)`.

Comment: Replace list with lst (i.e. don't use built-in functions as variable names). 
 Then 3rd column is: list(zip(*lst))[2]

Comment: @DarrylG should be `list(list(zip(*lst))[2])`

Comment: Whatever answer you get, keep in mind it *will* use loops *somewhere*. Whether or not they will be explicit or written in Python or C that's another question, and I'm sure that also matlab's `list(:,3)` is also using a loop somewhere

Comment: @daveshkumarsingh--yes, caught it just before seeing your message by loooking at the first answer.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh--list(list(zip(*lst))[2]) and list(zip(*lst))[2] produces the same result.  We need list(zip(...)) but why would you need list(list(...)))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly use Numpy to help you achieve this.

```py
import numpy as np
list = np.array([
       [111, 111, 4523.123, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4526.15354, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4580.112, 111, 111],
       ])
list[:,2]
```

I don't think you can achieve this with the native python list without using any loops.

Comment: It's possible without *explicit* loop as posted in the comments to the question

Comment: Right, explicit or non-explicit, it would still require a loop. I thought the OP would want to completely avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Using zip to transpose columns to rows, then selecting the 3rd sublist (row)

```
lst = [
       [111, 111, 4523.123, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4526.15354, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4580.112, 111, 111],
       ]
```

3rd column:

```
list(zip(*lst))[2]
```

Comment: `list(zip(...))` are probably two loops, one for sure.

Comment: @Adirio--no loops normally mean no for loops.  All these solutions uses builtin function which uses loops internally.

Comment: Yes, I agree, just pointing it out that, as @DeepSpace commented in several places in this question, not having explicit loops doesn't mean there are no loops.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is a very good solution:

```
import numpy as np


list = [
       [111, 111, 4523.123, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4526.15354, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4580.112, 111, 111],
       ]

np_list = np.array(list)[:,2]
```

For more complicated data manipulation, I would recommend using `pandas.DataFrame` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

If you must use list, you can try list comprehension. This is technically a loop, but use much shorter syntax and is a very pythonic way of working with collections. It also saves you from a need of using external libraries:

```
>>> list = [
...        [111, 111, 4523.123, 111, 111],
...        [111, 111, 4526.15354, 111, 111],
...        [111, 111, 4580.112, 111, 111],
...        ]
>>> l = [ x[2] for x in list ]
>>> l
[4523.123, 4526.15354, 4580.112]
```

Comment: `pandas` is probably an overkill. Just `numpy` is enough

Comment: A list comprehension is a loop

Comment: Even though it is technically a loop, it is still one line statement which may fit to the author needs. I agree that numpy is the best option, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the library `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np


list = [
       [111, 111, 4523.123, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4526.15354, 111, 111],
       [111, 111, 4580.112, 111, 111],
       ]

np_list = np.array(list)
third_col = np_list[:,2] # counting starts from 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not, but you can make a class that handles it. Basically you need to override the `__getitem__` method of the class, check if the passed value is a tuple, and in that case return accordingly:

```py
class MatlabList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 1:
            return super().__init__(args)
        return super().__init__(*args)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            # Remove the non-needed tuple in case it onle has one element
            if len(item) == 1:
                return self[item[0]]
            if isinstance(item[0], slice):
                return MatlabList(map(lambda x: x[item[1:]], self[item[0]]))
            return self[item[0]][item[1:]]
        return super().__getitem__(item)

lst = MatlabList(
    MatlabList(111, 111, 4523.123, 111, 111),
    MatlabList(111, 111, 4526.15354, 111, 111),
    MatlabList(111, 111, 4580.112, 111, 111),
)

lst[1,2]  # cell at 2nd row, 3rd column
lst[1,:]  # 2nd row
lst[:,2]  # 3rd column
```

Comment: `MatlabList(lst)[2]` returns the third row, not the third column

Comment: @DeepSpace that is also Matlab's behavior, it should be `[:, 2]` if you want the column.

Comment: I realized that `[:, 2]` won't work either as the first index will return a list and the second subscript needs to be applied to each. Will try to fix.

Comment: Could you show the usage syntax of retrieving the 3rd column using your solution?  Thanks.

Comment: @DarrylG done, I had to fix an issue when slices were provided for rows instead of columns, so thank you for your comment.